# how to pass a instance to a class that must implement an interface and then use it in java?

Tags: java, interface

I want pass a class-instace to a method of an other and be sure that it implements the needed interface. The code is something like this

```
public interface MyInterface{
   someMethod();
}

public class A implements MyInterface{
    B bInst;
    public someMethod(){
        //stuff
    }

    public bar(){
        bInst = new B(this); // [4]
    }
}

public class B{

    private MyInterface x;       //[1]

    // here i don't want to use 
    void B( MyInterface y ){     // [2]
        this.x=y;            // [3]
    }

    private void foo(){
        x.someMethod();
    }

}
```

I tried subsituting  "MyInterface" in [1] and [2] with "Class< ? extends IBtBytesReciever>" but compiler give me errors or in [2] or in [3].

What is the best way to implement my idea?

NOTE: I don't want to use directly class A because class B don't need to know the exact name of the class and it must be reusable with different classes

EDIT: the error is on [4]

```
 constructor B( class A ) not defined
```

Comment: What do you not like about `void B(MyInterface y)`? It seems to do exactly what you're saying..

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: By asking that the Object you pass in the Constructor of `B` is of Interface `MyInterface` you're already forcing your constraint.

Comment: @BrendanLong the error is "constructor B( class A ) not defined" in [4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "here i don't want to use" but basically your constructor isn't written properly. It should just be:

```
// Or make it non-public if you want, of course.
public B(MyInterface y) {
    this.x = y;
}
```

That will do *exactly* what you want: prevent anything which doesn't implement the interface from being passed to the constructor. Why would you want to make it generic, or pass in a class reference instead?

You *could* change it to:

```
public B(Class<? extends MyInterface> clazz) {
    // TODO: catch or declare all the various exceptions this could throw
    this.x = clazz.newInstance();
}
```

... but it feels pretty awkward to do so.

EDIT: Just to make it clear, it's absolutely *fine* to call `new B(this)`. Short but complete example, using your code as a starter:

```
interface MyInterface{
    void someMethod();
}

class A implements MyInterface{
    B bInst;
    public void someMethod(){
    }

    public void bar() {
        bInst = new B(this);
    }
}

class B {
    private MyInterface x;

    B(MyInterface y) {
        this.x=y;
    }

    private void foo(){
        x.someMethod();
    }    
}
```

That will work absolutely fine.

Comment: @Zorb: So that's fine - you can pass the same reference to the `B` constructor multiple times... it's really not clear what the first approach *doesn't* achieve that you want...

Comment: the problem is in firs way i can't call "bInst = new B(this);" because the constructor is for MyInterface and not for the class I call from

Comment: @Zorb: If you're within a class which implements `MyInterface` (such as `A`), you absolutely *can* call `new B(this)` - what makes you think you can't?

Comment: my compiler don't want, it says constructor B( class A) not defined, because i'm calling it from the A with new B(this)

Comment: @Zorb: Did you try compiling *exactly* the code presented in my edit? I can assure you, it works. But you had a bunch of syntax errors I had to fix up, which could have been misleading you. **Try the code I presented**.

Comment: you was right, under java it work perfectly :-o , this same pattern under android give me the problem i described, and i can understand why, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

> I tried subsituting "MyInterface" in [1] and [2] with "Class< ? extends IBtBytesReciever>"

That's your error. `Class<? extends IBtBytesReciever>` describes the type of a *class object*, which you might need for reflection, but you shouldn't need it here.

The difference between a class object and a class instance is like the difference between a wikipedia entry about elephants and one particular elephant. The wikipedia entry contains metadata about elephants in general, but if you want to perform an operation on an elephant, in most cases you need an actual elephant.

In a method like this:

```
 void foo(MyInterface instance)
 {

 }
```

you can call `foo()` with any valid instance of a class that implements MyInterface.